# Advice on creating custom base DLL build

Tags: dll, ckeditor5

Currently, we have a [custom CKEditor build](https://github.com/craftcms/ckeditor/blob/main/src/web/assets/ckeditor/src/ckeditor.js) including many 1st party plugins, and a couple of custom ones.

I want to allow other developers to load plugins without rebuilding, which would seem where DLL builds come in.

I could just use the pre-built base DLL build CKE provides and then load each plugin separately, but that's a lot of requests to tack on to every page.

So, it would seem I would want to create my own base DLL build. Is there any guidance on this process, other than just mimicking [this](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/blob/master/scripts/dll/webpack.config.dll.js)?

Alternatively, it seems possible to use the provided base DLL build, and then create a DLL package that included all of our plugins. I'd be fine with always loading 2 scripts (plus any provided by developers), just not 30.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> I could just use the pre-built base DLL build CKE provides and then load each plugin separately, but that's a lot of requests to tack on to every page.

It shouldn't be a problem nowadays that there are that many JS scripts. There's HTTP2, there's caching.

However, if it really worries you, you can simply concatenate all these JS scripts, which shouldn't be a problem for CraftCMS, even when you don't have access to Node.js.

> So, it would seem I would want to create my own base DLL build. Is there any guidance on this process, other than just mimicking this?

No need for that. Just load all them separately (taking advantage of HTTP2's capabilities) or concatenate these files (which, I presume, you can somehow automate).

The latter option (automatic concatenation of all the needed files) is something that, AFAIR, Drupal 9.5+ does too.

Comment: Thanks, @Reinmar. I had the same thought…but in our case it would mean close to 50 scripts (plugins + translations), which seemed excessive even considering http2/caching.

I quickly found making my own DLL base didn't seem like a viable approach, as `moduleIds` and paths in the manifest need to be very specific.

Comment: Where I landed was a DLL-compat package that bundles all our plugins/config: https://github.com/craftcms/ckeditor/pull/97/files

The worst part was having to mimick what the package-tools webpack config does. I couldn't use it directly because it expects a specific package file structure.

If https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-package-generator/blob/master/packages/ckeditor5-package-tools/lib/utils/get-webpack-config-dll.js had more args to make a more flexible, I could have used it directly.

Comment: Good point on server-side concat…that would probably be a simpler approach.